# Oblivion freezes in Windows XP, doesn't let you switch to Desktop

Tags: windows-xp

When I play Oblivion on Windows XP SP3 the game gets stuck. I can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> (Windows XP still seems to run perfectly in the background) and it shows me the standard mouse cursor, but on the screen remains the frozen game and any click with the mouse brings me back to the frozen game. All I need is a way to force the game to minimize so I have access to the Task Manager to shut it down.

I tried anything starting with

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> (shows windows cursor but not desktop; clicks bring me back into the game)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd> (no reaction at all)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Esc</kbd> (no reaction anyway, guess that's not in use anymore, right?)
- all possible BREAK combination
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> (no reaction)
- a few combos I forgot to mention

Is there any workaround? I could also code something a bit, as long as I don't have to rewrite Windows.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Delete</kbd> does NOT work. Task Manager probably opens in the background but the program does not let me switch to desktop to use it. No matter what I do, the screen remains on the last frame of the game when it froze. In the background everything seems to work but I just cannot switch out in any way to use the task manager.

Comment: You should be aware that not all programs will continue to function if you minimize them.

Answer (score 2):

You could try CTRL+ALT+DEL to open Task Manager to kill Oblivion from there. It's common knowledge to know what CTRL+ALT+DEL is, so remember it for the future.

Answer (score 2):

CTRL+SHIFT+ESC should bring up Task Manager directly, or you can use CTRL+ALT+DELETE to access the Windows menu and select Task Manager from there.